# How to read EMREXTCREATEPEN from file?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

EMREXTCREATEPEN is a structure used in Windows enhanced meta files. It is defined like this:

```
typedef struct tagEMREXTCREATEPEN
{
    EMR     emr;
    DWORD   ihPen;              // Pen handle index
    DWORD   offBmi;             // Offset to the BITMAPINFO structure if any
    DWORD   cbBmi;              // Size of the BITMAPINFO structure if any
                                // The bitmap info is followed by the bitmap
                                // bits to form a packed DIB.
    DWORD   offBits;            // Offset to the brush bitmap bits if any
    DWORD   cbBits;             // Size of the brush bitmap bits if any
    EXTLOGPEN32 elp;            // The extended pen with the style array.
} EMREXTCREATEPEN, *PEMREXTCREATEPEN;
```

EXTLOGPEN32 is larger than 8 byte, which means elp is 8 byte aligned when compiling the above for x64 with the default struct alignment. However in *.emf files the struct seems to be 4 byte aligned, which means the C++ code will interpret the members of elp incorrectly.

What can you do in that case? The only solution I have come up with until now is to define my own struct MYEMREXTCREATEPEN with a 4 byte alignment and use that one instead of the original one. But isn't there a better solution?